# search by name or ip address from list in angular

Tags: angular

I have a list where i am getting system name with its ip address. I have a search bar. I want to search the list either by name or by ip address.  When I am searching list by name or ip address then i am not getting proper response.

*my component.html*

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" #name placeholder="Search by name or ip address.."
      (input)="onSearch($event.target.value)" autocomplete="off" name="search" />
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </div>
```

*my component.ts file*

```
onSearch(name) {
this.nameVal = name;
}
fetchList(){
this.service
    .listPagination(currentPage, itemsPerPage, this.nameVal)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
   console.log(res);})}
```

*component.service file*

```
  listPagination(currentPage, itemsPerPage, name): Observable<any[]> {
  let numbers = new RegExp(/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/);
  const numberCheck= numbers.test(name);
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('page', currentPage);
params = params.append('limit', itemsPerPage);
if(numberCheck === true){
  params = params.append('ipAddress', name);
 }
 else{
  params = params.append('name', name);
 }
const editUrl = `${this.fetchApi1}?${params}`;
return this.http.get<any>(editUrl);
 }
```

Comment: I think you have an error in onSearch() method, you are assigning 'event' to 'this.nameVal' , yet your param variable name is 'name', therefore, try updating to this 
`this.nameVal = name`

Comment: Yes i have corrected it now